# Web3J: Subscription code for listening to event is executing twice by two different threads

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java, parity-io

I am developing an app with SpringBoot and Web3J, where i use a **contract wrapper for interacting with Smart contract**. Here is the autogenerated code of a method for listening to an event, called NewId:

```
public Observable<NewIdEventResponse> newIdEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {
    final Event event = new Event("NewId", 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(),
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Bytes32>() {}, new TypeReference<Address>() {}));
    EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, getContractAddress());
    filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(event));
    return web3j.ethLogObservable(filter).map(new Func1<Log, NewIdEventResponse>() {
        @Override
        public NewIdEventResponse call(Log log) {
            EventValues eventValues = extractEventParameters(event, log);
            NewIdEventResponse typedResponse = new NewIdEventResponse();
            typedResponse.key = (Bytes32) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(0);
            typedResponse.contractId = (Address) eventValues.getNonIndexedValues().get(1);
            return typedResponse;
        }
    });
}
```

I've created a **subscription s to the observable, where i print the executing thread name AND increment a counter, initialized to 0**. Then "mian thread" (spring boot thread) sleeps for 5 seconds after doing subscription, and then prints counter value and invoke s.unsubscribe . Here is code:

```
//Invoke transactional contract method...
                this.counter = 0;
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                log.warn("Counter value before subscription: "+counter);
                Subscription s = contractWrapper.newIdEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
                        .subscribe(evento ->{
                            log.warn("Event Received");
                            log.warn("Thread Name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            latch.countDown();
                            this.testIncCounter();
                            },                              
                        Throwable::printStackTrace);

                latch.await();
                log.warn("Main Thread going to sleep for 5 seconds");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                log.warn("Unsubscribing...");
                s.unsubscribe();
                log.warn("Counter value "+counter);
```

The testIncCounter method is synchronized:

```
private synchronized void testIncCounter(){
        counter++;
    }
```

The problem is that **subscription code is executing twice by different threads**, as it can be seen in logs ,**and counter's end value is 2, and should be 1**. Here is the output:

```
2017-11-07 20:56:17.345  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Counter value before subscription: 0
2017-11-07 20:56:17.433  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Event Received
2017-11-07 20:56:17.433  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Thread Name http-nio-8090-exec-4
2017-11-07 20:56:17.449  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Main Thread going to sleep for 5 seconds
2017-11-07 20:56:17.491  WARN 23533 --- [ool-17-thread-1] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Event Received
2017-11-07 20:56:17.491  WARN 23533 --- [ool-17-thread-1] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Thread Name pool-17-thread-1
2017-11-07 20:56:22.450  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Unsubscribing...
2017-11-07 20:56:22.459  WARN 23533 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] com.ckgt.service.impl.CecaServiceImpl    : Counter value 2
```

Maybe is this a bug, or am i doing something wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.